# Where should Grails Command objects be placed in the project structure?

Tags: grails, groovy, command-objects

I have a class called LoginCommand in domain/my/package/name

```
class LoginCommand {

    String emailAddress
    String password

}
```

My question is why is a table be auto generated in my database for a ***Command object in grails?   Are these command objects supposed to be placed ouside of /domain to avoid auto generation of a table by hibernate/orm.

Answer (score 12):

They should not go in `grails-app/domain`; they are not domain classes.  Place them in `src/groovy`.  Alternatively, a common convention is to put the command class in the same file as the controller that uses it.

Take a look at the [Convention Over Configuration](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/gettingStarted.html#conventionOverConfiguration) section in the grails manual to get an idea of what goes where.